# IE8 space between divs is shrinking

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a menu built using divs, each section is composed by 2 divs (Title and content). The content is collapsed or expanded when the title is clicked, but on IE8 the space between the section divs is shrinking after expanding and collapsing a section.IE9, Chrome, and Firefox display everything correctly

[This](http://snag.gy/Lcvhb.jpg) is how it looks, the first section is displaying correctly with the space below it, but on the rest the space is shrinked

The weird thing is if I resize the window, everything looks fine [again](http://snag.gy/TLTwF.jpg)

[This](http://pastebin.com/YLD4ZgvA) is a sample of the code I'm using, and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pollirrata/YUGST/3/) is the jsfiddle

I hope somebody have solved the same issue. Thanks

Comment: wrap your title and content in a div and make the space up using the container div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

There is an explanation of the problem here :

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/animation-jump-quick-tip/

Effectively, wrap each pair of title and content elements in a containing div, and then apply your padding to the bottom of that. Tested in IE7, IE8,  FF, & Chrome

```
 <!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".menu-section-content").hide();
        $(".menu-section-title").click(function() {
            var theHeight = $(this).height();
            $(this).css('height', theHeight);
            $(this).next(".menu-section-content").slideToggle(600);
            $(this).toggleClass('collapse');
        });
    });
    </script>

    <style>
        div.menu-section-content
        {
            border: 1px solid #777;
            border-top: none;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
        div.menu-section-title
        {
            font-size: 100%;
            border: solid 1px #777777; /*border-radius: 5px 0px 0 0;*/
            background-color: #A9C3C4;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 500;
            margin-left: 5px;
            cursor: pointer;
            clear: both;
            padding: 5px;


        }
        .expand
        {
            background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/1a/Silk_bullet_arrow_up.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right center;
        }
        .collapse
        {
            background-image: url('http://souper-spices.com/wp-content/themes/shopperpress/template_shopperpress/images/langs/arrow.png');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right center;
        }

        .container {
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-section-title expand">
    title
    </div>

    <div class="menu-section-content">
        options
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-section-title expand">
    title
    </div>

    <div class="menu-section-content">
        options
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="menu-section-title expand">
    title
    </div>

    <div class="menu-section-content">
        options
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container"> 
    <div class="menu-section-title expand">
    title
    </div>

    <div class="menu-section-content">
        options
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```